# Reprap Ormerod 2 Duet web control not automatically starting, how can I fix?

Tags: reprap, firmware

I have an Ormerod 2 which is controlled by an Duet board with original up to date firmware. When I power it on and try to use the web interface (web control) it seems to not have started. When I connect my printer to my laptop and use Pronterface (printer interface) to send t0 to the printer it replies

`Starting network...
RepRapFirmware is up and running.
Starting DHCP
Network up, IP=censored`

which leads me to the conclusion that the printer isn't starting its firmware and the web interface before that. 
After sending t0 and waiting 10sec for these replies it works fine.

Every source says it should start automatically.

So my question is how do I fix that? or what even is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For everyone wondering: One time I let the printer sit powered on for ~1h before trying to connect and use Pronterface, same story as above.

Comment: Hmm - this is an old one, so I'll assume it worked somehow. What versions of firmware did you have? What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is to update firmware to the newest version: https://github.com/dc42/RepRapFirmware/releases

See details on Duet wiki page: https://duet3d.dozuki.com/Guide#Section_Updating_Firmware_and_Duet_Web_Control